# Flask url handling for port

Tags: python, flask, kibana, flask-login

I have Kibana (part of elasticsearch stack) running on xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5601. Since Kibana does not have authentication of its own, I am trying to wrap it under my flask login setup. In other words, if someone tries to visit xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5601, I need the page to be redirected to my flask login page. I can use the @login_required decorator on the URL to achieve this...but I don't know how to setup the flask route URL to handle the port 5601 since it needs to begin with a leading slash.

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT
@senaps: App 1 is flask that runs on 0.0.0.0, port 9500, App 2 is node.js based Kibana that I can choose to either run on localhost port 5601 and then expose via nginx, or i can directly make public on IP:5601. Either way, it is running as a "service" on startup and listening on 5601 at all times.

Problem statement - App 2 to be wrapped under App 1 login. I do not want to use nginx for authentication of App 2 but rather the App 1 flask login setup.

I'm currently using gunicorn to serve flask app and have nginx reverse proxy setup to route to flask app. Guide followed is [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Option 1 - Node.js Kibana application exposed to public on IP:5601.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
}}
```

If I visit IP, it goes to my flask app, great. I'm unable to figure out how to handle flask view URL if someone visits IP:5601. Instead of taking them to Kibana, it should redirect to my flask app for authentication.

I tried adding another server block to listen at 5601 and proxy_pass to the flask sock file, I get a nginx error that says it cannot bind to 5601 and asks me to kill the listener at 5601. But I need Kibana running at 5601 at all times (unless I can figure out a way to launch this service via python flask).

Option 2 - Kibana application runs on localhost port 5601 mounted at "/kibana" in order to not conflict with "/" needed for flask. Then it is exposed via nginx reverse proxy.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock;
}
location /kibana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite /kibana/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}}
```

With this setup, one can access Kibana by going to IP/kibana. But problem with Option 2 is if I have a /kibana view in my flask app to catch it, it does not take effect as redirection to Kibana happens at nginx, so flask never gets involved.

I coudln't find much info on stack etc. since most solutions deal with using nginx to authenticate Kibana and not any other python applications.

Given this, how would I corporate your solution? Many thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to proxy all traffic to the Kibana server through the Flask application.  You can use a catch-all route to handle forwarding of the different paths.  You would disallow access to Kibana from sources other than from the Flask application.

```
import requests  # may require `pip install requests`

kibana_server_baseurl = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5601/'

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
@login_required
def proxy_kibana_requests(path):
    # ref http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/118/
    url = kibana_server_baseurl + path
    req = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type = req.headers['content-type'])
```

Another options is to use Nginx as a reverse proxy and use Nginx to handle authentication.  The simplest, if it meets your needs, is to use basic auth. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-basic/.

Alternatively you could check for a custom header in the Nginx config on access to the Kibana application and redirect to the Flask application if it were missing.

Another option is to use an existing Kibana authentication proxy. A commercial option, Elastic x-pack is a popular option.  Another OSS option is https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy.  I have not personally used either.

Comment: let me clarify a little more, it certainly is not to bind to port 5601, my flask is running on a separate port. 

my flask app is hosted on AWS on a static IP xx.xxx.xxx.xxx. So say I have the following views (as an example)

when i visit xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, it is caught by @app.route("/")
when i visit xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login, it is caught by @app.route("/login")
etc...

now, i have another application currently exposed to public on xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5601.

the question is how do i catch this URL so i can redirect it to the appropriate handler?

Comment: Often in cases like this where flask is handling authentication, you might proxy all requests. That is, all external access would go through the flask server and, if authenticated, be proxied to the kibana server so that the user never directly communicates with the kibana server.  The flask server cannot see traffic on the kibana port. If you wanted the flask server just to set a header or cookie and redirect to the kibana server, the kibana server would need to changed to check for the auth token and redirect to the flask server if it were missing.

Comment: @ArunRamachandran I updated the response to show how you might proxy traffic to the kibaba server.  You could then use a firewall rule and, depending on your topology, limit the bind interface to restrict access to the kibana server.

Comment: my preference is to solve it by proxying all traffic using flask - that makes most sense. Nginx basic auth means the user has to auth twice - flask login and then nginx auth, i want to avoid this. I sort of get how your catch all snippet works (very clever), however, when I set kibana_server_baseurl = staticIP:5601, flask still does not catch it. Flask catches any staticIP/path but not staticIP:5601. It still opens up Kibana. The @app.route begins with "/path", not sure how to set it up with ":5601/. Is this the issue? Thoughts?

Comment: as you said, if flask can never listen to traffic on port 5601, maybe this is not possible. I'm also willing to explore nginx basic auth if i can figure out how to avoid double authentication. In other words, say i set a basic auth in nginx config. A user logs into my flask app, then nagivates to the page that has an embedded kibana dashboard via iframe. Now, when page renders, nginx will prompt for authentication. Is there a way to make the code provide this so user does not? I've read about pre-flight ajax request but i dont know how to pull this off.

Comment: as for the third option of custom header, i will need help executing this. I think i can figure out how to check for custom header in nginx and this will prevent direct access to Kibana. However, I will need to provide access to Kibana inside my flask app via an iframe. How would i provide the custom header in the URL so nginx does not redirect it to my flask again?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran 1. With Nginx basic auth in front of the Kibana server, you would presumably no longer use the Flask server at all. 2. If you proxy all traffic on port 80 the user would never communicate over port 5601.  With the configuration you have described, all traffic would traverse this chain: `Client <-- port 80 --> Flask <-- port 5601 --> Kibana`.  In this scenario, client direct access to 5601 should be denied.  3. The custom header option is more complicated than the other options.  I suspect you will that find one of the other options may be easier.

Comment: maybe i'm completely missing your point (i'm very much a novice in all this setup trying to learn as i go along). i proxy all traffic on 80 to my flask app (see nginx setup in my post). At the same time, I need to open up port 5601 so the kibana iframe link IP:5601 works. Flask is not able to catch any traffic on IP:5601. I'm unable to deny client direct access to 5601 using flask. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @ArunRamachandran. Comments are not ideal for this discussion.  As you have configured it, you would no longer use port 5601 for the Kibana dashboard but rather port 80.  At the risk of opening a rabbit hole, depending on your needs one could put the flask app at port 5601 and move the Kibana server to another port so you do not need to reconfigure the clients.

Answer (score 0):

so you have 2 separate apps right?
you want the second app to only work if user is authenticated with first app.

simplest way would be, to use the same db.this way, flask login would check for the user's authentication based on the same db. with that being said, you may not be able to handle session's perfectly okay.

the trick is in `uwsgi` nad `nginx`. you should use `Emperor` mode of `uwsgi` so both apps are deployed.

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def function()
```

now, the question might be how would we get the second app's `/` route if the first app has that route too. well, this will not be a problem since the url is different. but you need your `nginx` configured to relay requests for `xx.x.x.x` to the first app and `x.x.x.x:y` to the second app.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port80/
}

server {
    listen       5601;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port81/
}
```

since you asked for suggestions on how to do it, i don't include codes. so you can figure out based on your setup. or you should tell us how you setup and serve the two apps, so we could provide more of code.